# How do I choose where the PDF files are created?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, texlive, linux, directory

Noob Linux user here!

When compiling a file on the terminal it always creates the file in the /home directory.
Is there a way to change the directory where the PDF file is going to be created?

Answer (score 1):

By default `pdflatex` will place the output in the current directory.

You can usually get usage details for a program either by running `man` or passing one of `-h`, `--help`, or `-help` to the program.

In this case either `man pdflatex` or `pdflatex -help` will give you (among other things):

```
-output-directory=DIR   use existing DIR as the directory to write files in
```

So if you run `pdflatex -output-directory=/some/path/to/dir foo.tex` then `foo.pdf` (along with other intermediary files) will be placed in `/some/path/to/dir`.